# Discover every stock listed on the NASDAQ?

Tags: stocks, nasdaq

Where would I go to find every stock listed on the NASDAQ stock exchange and how can I be notified/discover if a stock leaves or is added to this list in the future?

Comment: Are you refering to NASDAQ-100, NASDAQ Composite, or literally the whole NASDAQ?

Comment: The whole nasdaq, my post is now edited to reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NASDAQ offers a [downloadable directory](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=symbollookup) of its stocks.  On the left side, look for **Downloadable Files**.

They also offer a list of [issues that are pending suspension or delisting](https://listingcenter.nasdaq.com/IssuersPendingSuspensionDelisting.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The list of symbols can be found on [nasdaqtrader.com](https://nasdaqtrader.com). Navigate to the "Symbol Directory" near to top-right of the page and selected "NASDAQ-Listed" under the "Downloadable Files" menu. According to the site, "All information is as of the current trading day.".

The URL with the text file is http://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/dynamic/SymDir/nasdaqlisted.txt.

Source: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1640